# Trying to log "alert" from a Push notification userInfo dictionary but getting null

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have this method in my AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground  )
    {
        //restore push
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"appRestorePush" object:nil];

    }

    else {

        //push for when the app is open
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"appOpenPush" object:nil];
        NSString *alert = [userInfo objectForKey:@"alert"];
        NSLog(@"%@",alert);
    }


}
```

I want to log the alert in the console but for some reason I am getting null. Any push messages sent use this code:

```
//set the message and data
            NSString *pushMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message! %@ %@",message, self.currentUser.username];
            NSDictionary *pushData = @{@"alert": pushMessage, @"badge": @0, @"sound": @"alert.wav"};
            PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
            [push setQuery:pushQuery];
            [push setData:pushData];
```

There should be a string in "alert". Any ideas why I am getting null?